# Automatic start Chronometer in Android

Tags: java, android, chronometer

I would like to ask how can I able to start my chronometer without clicking a button? For example, if I click the "Play" button, the next chronometer in the next layout will automatically start.

I tried to just start it in my level 1 class, but after I run it, I got this error in my console:

```
ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front.
```

I have this code for my Chronometer:

```
Chronometer chrono = null;
chrono.start();

chrono = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.timer);
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Here it is: Chronometer chrono = null; chrono.start(); chrono = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.timer);

Comment: @flp just updated the post :)

Comment: Where do you call this code snippet?
looks like you have to find the view first and then start it.

Comment: inside my OnCreate method in my level 1 class. Where should I put this?

Comment: try to call chrono.start() after findbyviewid

Comment: I also tried it, but failed.